# how the uncertain data will be clustered using K-medoid algorithm on the basis of their probability distribution similarity?

Tags: cluster-analysis

what is uncertain data clustering?how can we cluster the uncertain data based on their probability distribution similarity?how the uncertain data will be clustered using K-medoid algorithm on the basis of their probability distribution similarity?

Answer (score 1):

K-Medoids itself will not take care of uncertainty.

It's up to you, to take care of handling uncertain data by choosing an appropriate distance function.